# SyntaxError: Identifier 'embed' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, discord

i need help with this
`SyntaxError: Identifier 'embed' has already been declared`

When i try to make
  `if (owner && msg.author.id !== 725959811434414091) return;`

than i create a embed with using `let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()` 
it say

```
            ^
SyntaxError: Identifier 'embed' has already been declared
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at C:\Users\serveradmin\Desktop\backup\node_modules\require-all\index.js:52:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at requireAll (C:\Users\serveradmin\Desktop\backup\node_modules\require-all\index.js:34:9
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: on that, i can't solved with [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Identifier+has+already+been+declared+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to rename your variable `embed` to something else, as this name seems to already be used higher in your file.

If you can't, or don't want to, simply press `Ctrl` and `F` at the same time on your code editor, and search for all occurrences of `embed`, to find out where the other declaration was made.